# Initially horizontal geodesic is always horizontal

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to prove the following.

> Let $E,B$ be Riemannian manifolds. Suppose
> $\pi: E\to B$ is a Riemannian submersion.
>
> For each $x\in E$, define $V_x E = \ker \pi_{*}$ and $H_xE = (V_x
>  E)^{\perp}$. $W\in T_x E$ is said to be *horizontal* if  $W\in H_x E$.
>
> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to E$ be a geodesic curve such that $\gamma'(0)$ is
> horizontal. Prove that $\gamma'(t)$ is horizontal for all $t\in
>  [0,1]$.

**My attempt**

Firstly, for any smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to B$, there is always a locally defined *horizontal lift* to $E$. That is, for any $p\in \pi^{-1}(\gamma(0))$, there is $\epsilon>0$ and a smooth curve $\gamma_E:[0,\epsilon) \to E$ such that $\pi\circ \gamma_E = \gamma$, $\gamma_E(0)=p$ and $\gamma_E'$ is always horizontal.

So, we take a geodesic on $B$ with initial condition $\gamma_B(0)=\pi\circ\gamma(0), \gamma_B'(0)=\pi_{*}\gamma'(0)$. We can do so (at least locally) through the uniqueness and existence of geodesic.

Then, take a horizontal lift $\gamma_E:I\to E$ with $\gamma_E(0)=\gamma(0)$. Here, $I$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$ containing $0$.

We can prove that $\gamma_E$ is a geodesic. (This argument is not the main topic of this question.)

Then, by the uniqueness of geodesic, we have $\gamma_E(t) = \gamma(t)$ for $t\in I$.

**Here is the question.** It seems that we need to prove that $I$ is a closed(and therefore clopen) set of $[0,1]$, too. Then since $[0,1]$ is connected we have $I=[0,1]$. But I do not know how to do it.

For example, [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Riemannian_Geometry/wEcBBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=initially+horizontal++submersion&pg=PA101&printsec=frontcover) on the proof of Proposition 2.109, (ii),

(Here $\tilde{c}$ corresponds to our $\gamma$, and $c$ corresponds to $\gamma_B$)

> ...Hence the set of parameters where the geodesic $\tilde{c}$ is
> horizontal, and where it is a lift of $c$ is an open set containing
> $0$. These two conditions being also closed, they are satisfied on the
> maximal interval of definition of $\tilde{c}$.

Any help?

Comment: Also posted on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435401/initially-horizontal-geodesic-is-always-horizontal/435405#435405